# instantiated from here error with a predicate template function

Tags: c++, size

I tried researching this question already, but it seems as though every question dealing with my error has to do with classes and their default constructors whereas my code contains no classes. It's a simple size() function that returns the number of elements in a given array. (I'm aware there is a built in size() function, that's not the point).

I at first thought that it was upset with my naming my function size() when a size() function already existed so I changed mine to sise() but I still recieve the same error and have no idea how to solve it.

Code:

```
template<class T > int sise(T array[], int count){
  if(array[count+1]== NULL){
    return count+1;
  }
  else{
    return sise(array,count+1);
  }
}

template <class T> int sise(T array[]){
  return sise(array , 0);
  }

int main(){
  int array[] = {1 , 7 , 5, 4, 6 ,2 , 3};
  int len = sise<int>(array);
  std::cout << len << std::endl;
  //print<int>(array);
  //  shakersort<int>(array);
  // print<int>(array);

  return 0;
}
```

Don't worry about the commented out function calls in main(), as each respective's calls functions have been commented out but the same error of

```
Shakersort.cpp: In function ‘int sise(T*, int) [with T = int]’:
Shakersort.cpp:60:24:   instantiated from ‘int sise(T*) [with T = int]’
Shakersort.cpp:77:28:   instantiated from here
Shakersort.cpp:51:3: warning: NULL used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
```

is given. What is going on?

Comment: Your int array[] is not null terminated so your size calculation isn't going to work even when it does compile. Your NULL is defined as a pointer and is being compared to an int.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is warning about `NULL` being compared to an `int` from the looks of it. Not strictly an error (nor is it made an error) but a likely indication of false assumptions being made. One such assumption seems to be that arrays are magically null-terminated: they are not. That is something very specific to string literals and even then the null-terminator is not `NULL` but rather `'\0'`. You'll either need to pass the size of the array along or you'll need to deduce it using a template, e.g.:

```
template <typename T, int Size>
int sise(T (&array)[Size], int count) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I don't think the `sise` function should have a second parameter, for reasons of logic, and based on how the OP wants to call it in `main`.

Comment: @NicholasM: That is quite possible: I just used roughly the same set of parameters as in the original declaration, just also adding size deduction of the array. I assumed that the `count` would be used to indicate the current position considered for the sorting or something. My main points were to address the warning and mentioning that the array size needs to come from somewhere. I made no attempt to correct the logic.